# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError" in Jupiter-notebook?

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

Well, I am trying to write a starvation DHCP attack code through the following code.

I have tried `pip install scapy` and also `pip install --pre` but they do not work. I am running the program on windows. The problem is with `from scapy.all import *` line:

```
import sys
import os
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
from scapy.all import *
```

...

Here is the error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy'`

What should I do?

Comment: "they do not work" is not specific enough. Are you getting error messages? Do the commands succeed, but the module still appears not installed?

Comment: @ForceBru Yes there are no problems when I run the commands but still there is the error.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you have not successfully installed scapy in a place that python is expecting it. I expect that you have not installed scapy successfully at all, based on installation methods you have tried.

I would recommend following the Windows specific scapy documentation found here: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#windows

`pip install` is not supported for scapy on Windows.

See the relevant section below:

> You need the following software in order to install Scapy on Windows:
>
> Python: Python 2.7.X or 3.4+. After installation, add the Python
>   installation directory and its Scripts subdirectory to your PATH.
>   Depending on your Python version, the defaults would be C:\Python27
>   and C:\Python27\Scripts respectively.
>
> Npcap: the latest version.
>   Default values are recommended. Scapy will also work with Winpcap.
>
> Scapy: latest development version from the Git repository. Unzip the
>   archive, open a command prompt in that directory and run python
>   setup.py install. Just download the files and run the setup program.
>   Choosing the default installation options should be safe. (In the case
>   of Npcap, Scapy will work with 802.11 option enabled. You might want
>   to make sure that this is ticked when installing).
>
> After all packages are installed, open a command prompt (cmd.exe) and
>   run Scapy by typing scapy. If you have set the PATH correctly, this
>   will find a little batch file in your C:\Python27\Scripts directory
>   and instruct the Python interpreter to load Scapy.